# What could be cross-functional DevOps questions?

Tags: discussion

I think most powerful "human" thing about DevOps is breaking down the silos and creating new ways of communication.

Previously we have had the culture tag trending quite well, but of course the number of quesions is totally biased to tech which is quite ok to start with.

But look, it seems like most of those culture questions have been asked by tech-related individuals, most far distance I have perceived are perspectives from high-level IT project managers.

Fair enough.

Then, there is a question asked here by a recruiter - 42p score an 8K views. Is quite kind of a big bang for this community - right?

Ok then, I did an experiment and asked a question on LinkedIn to non-tech roles what would they ask and invited them to join here. Let's see what happens.

Enough explanation, hope you are still with me. Thank you :-)

**Now my question:**

- What could be DevOps questions we would like to ask ask other roles and perspectives down the whole value chain? (I mean, if we do not, what about our own perception of importance of empathy and culture we claim with DevOps?)

Hope this does make sense to you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure I understand your question but here's my thoughts, feel free to comment if I got it wrong.

First, concerning the question with 8k views, it probably did end up in Hot Network Question because it got votes and answers quickly ([description of the algorithm here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-questions-in-the-hot-tab-selected), which usually bring more people to it.
It did gather 42 votes from 8k views, which is not such a good ratio nor an indication of a big bang for this community, it's more an outlier. You can compare this to [What's the difference between DevOps and Automation?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3/13) which has 32 votes for only 639 views.

Now to answer the question:

Any question related to DevOps (culture/methodology) and the tooling for software lifecycle (infrastructure automation/build/CI/CD) from anyone of any role is welcome.
General rule apply that the question should be scoped enough to not need writing a book to answer it. If the question is too broad, wording it on a real life exemple could help narrowing the scope.

I won't try writing a list of questions "we" would like to see, I really prefer letting all question in and if a bad pattern arise we'll handle it when it comes.

Comment: sure - I was just wondering what could be examples if cross-functional question reflecting a de-silosing process.

Comment: No problem, Don't feel any obligation to accept an answer if you think it doesn't really address you question, we're on meta, I just dropped my thoughts about what I understood from you concern. I think exemples should come on main but I'm not in any way the ultimate reference of what devops.se should allow :)

Comment: By 'we're on meta' I mean it's absolutely OK to leave a question open for some days to gather more opinions, that's why meta exist after all, gathering diverse opinions